# ASP.NET global.asax end_session (session never end)

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have got a problem with end session. All the time when I click button in "WebForms.asax" session count time from zero to one minute(if I will click this buton session will never end). I gave value 1 minute to end all sessions and it`s work when I not click on website. Do you know where is a problem?

here I start session:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace Session_Test
{
    public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Session["UserAuthentication"] = "dddd";
            TypSession.InnerHtml = "<a href='WebForm1.aspx'>sdsds</a>";
        }
    }
}
```

Another website (WebForm1.aspx):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace Session_Test
{
    public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            example.InnerHtml = Session["UserAuthentication"].ToString()+"         "+ Session.Timeout.ToString();;
        }

        protected void Unnamed1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Response.Redirect(Request.RawUrl);
            Session.Abandon();

        }
    }
}
```

global.asax

```
 void Session_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Session.Timeout = 1; 
        }

        void Session_End(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Response.Redirect("http://localhost:51888/Default.aspx");
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Response.Redirect(Request.RawUrl);
```

Will end your respones, it is the same as calling:

```
Response.Redirect(Request.RawUrl, true);
```

where the bool stands for stop the response, so your Session.Abandon() will never be called. If you want to do Session.Abandon() after your redirect you should call redirect with false:

```
Response.Redirect(Request.RawUrl, false);
```

[Redirect MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/08za4s98.aspx)

Comment: Each time you come on a page in your website the session timeout will be reset to 1 min.

Comment: How can I end session? for example for user who leave website? or refresh website?

Comment: Session.Abandon() will end the session when excecuting/rendering a page. There is no need to end a session when an user leaves, the session will be handled and ended by iis.